# LIBOR Reform creates Winners and Losers

Tags: interest-rate, markets, market-indexes

One phrase I heard of the reform to move away from LIBOR is that it would create winners and losers.  Can someone explain how this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that LIBOR is going away is because it was susceptible to manipulation by its member banks. So whether you're a "winner" or a "loser" depends on what the banks actually did and how it affected you.

If the banks artificially kept LIBOR rates low, then borrowers won (because they paid less interest) and lenders/investors lost (because they received less return on their investments). So the shift would be a "win" for investors/lenders (higher returns) and a "loss" for borrowers (higher interest rates).

The opposite would be true if banks artificially *inflated* rates.

It's hard to say if either actually happened, since there's not a good way to know what rates *should* have been to know if they were being manipulated.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems a bit silly as they can still manipulate rates.  LIBOR was just the conduit that will just be something else from now go forward.

Comment: @PeteB. The "something else" that is currently proposed is based off of market transactions (repos) versus a "committee" of 16 banks. So yes, there may be some room for manipulation, but I would argue that the market (in theory) will make that much harder (or expensive).